# std::istream_iterator, memory consumption

Tags: c++, stl, istream-iterator

I try to iterate through a text file using iterators:

```
1) std::istream_iterator<MyData> itRecordStreamBegin(fileStream);
2) std::istream_iterator<MyData> itRecordStreamEnd;
```

After the first line it reads some data from the file (it uses operator >> for MyData type). As expected.

Unfortunately after that memory consumption rises and it seems like `istream_iterator` tried to load whole file in memory. Several seconds later (when there are out_of_memory exceptions thrown) debugger gets into the second line. But file reading failed and I cannot read anything more.

**Questions**:

Is this correct behaviour for `istream_iterator` (to load file into memory)?

I do not observe this for smaller files (like 20MB).

Maybe for such large file I need to use common `getline` way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `istream_iterator` just uses the `>>` operator on the type.  It keeps at most *one* instance of the type in memory.  When using it, you *do* make copies of the instance.  I would suspect (but without seeing the code) that either your copy constructor or destructor is defective, or you leak memory somewhere in your `>>` operator.  I would be very surprised if the problem is related to `istream_iterator`.

Comment: you are right! I will have to investigate this >> operator. Thanks for the answer